# splitting multivalued field while importing data into solr

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around solr 3.4 when it comes to multiple values. I have this DIH:

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="********" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lokal" user="****" password="******" />
    <document>
        <entity name="Search" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="select b_id, b_navn, b_cats, b_info, b_keyword, b_critical, b_geo, b_adress from searchbiz">
            <field column="b_id" name="b_id" />
            <field column="b_info" name="b_info" />
            <field column="b_cats" name="b_cats" splitBy=","/>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Now, my problem is when this b_cats is index'ed Im getting this result :

```xml
<arr name="b_adress">
  <str>place1, place2</str>
</arr>
```

But I thought it should be one  node on each.

When I try to facet using this field, I'm getting "place1, place2" = xx result, instead of place1 = xx, and place2 xx.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction on this problem?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I don't see in your example where you are splitting the values going into the b_adress field, only the b_info field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```xml
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="********" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lokal"     user="****" password="******" />
<document>
    <entity name="Search" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="select b_id, b_navn, b_cats, b_info, b_keyword, b_critical,     b_geo, b_adress from searchbiz">
        <field column="b_id" name="b_id" />
        <field column="b_info" name="b_info" />
        <field column="b_cats" splitBy="," sourceColName="b_cats"/>
    </entity>
</document>
```