# Splitting database column into multivalued Solr field

Tags: solr, dih

I'm going nuts trying to figure out how to get the Data Import Handler's `splitBy` construct to work. I was expecting it to split the input column into a multivalued field. Here's a test case to reproduce the problem:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;
import org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestSplitBy {

  SolrServer server;
  File configPath = new File(FileUtils.getTempDirectory(), Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));

  String solrconfig_xml = "<config><luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_41</luceneMatchVersion><requestHandler name=\"search\" class=\"solr.SearchHandler\" default=\"true\"><lst name=\"defaults\"><str name=\"fl\">*</str><str name=\"df\">id</str></lst></requestHandler><requestHandler name=\"/dataimport\" class=\"org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler\"><lst name=\"defaults\"><str name=\"config\">data-config.xml</str></lst></requestHandler></config>";

  String data_config_xml = "<dataConfig>" +
      "<dataSource url=\"jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb\" user=\"SA\" driver=\"org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver\" />" +
      "<document>" +
      "<entity name=\"item\" transformer=\"RegexTransformer\" query=\"SELECT * FROM test\">" +
      "<field column=\"type\" name=\"type\" splitBy=\",\" />" +
      "</entity>" +
      "</document>" +
      "</dataConfig>";

  String schema_xml = "<schema version=\"1.3\" name=\"test\">" +
      "<types>" +
      "<fieldType name=\"string\" class=\"solr.StrField\" sortMissingLast=\"true\" omitNorms=\"true\" />" +
      "</types>" +
      "<fields>" +
      "<field stored=\"true\" name=\"id\" type=\"string\" />" +
      "<field stored=\"true\" name=\"type\" type=\"string\" multiValued=\"true\"/>" +
      "</fields>" +
      "<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>" +
      "</schema>";

  DataSource getDataSource() {
    JDBCDataSource ds = new JDBCDataSource();
    ds.setUser("SA");
    ds.setUrl("mem:testdb");
    return ds;
  }

  void populateDb(DataSource ds) {
    QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner(ds);
    try {
      runner.update("DROP TABLE test IF EXISTS");
      runner.update("CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER, type VARCHAR(256));");
      runner.update("INSERT INTO test VALUES 1, 'foo,bar,baz'");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }

  void writeSolrConfig() throws IOException {
    File corePath = new File(configPath, "collection1");
    corePath.mkdir();
    File confPath = new File(corePath, "conf");
    confPath.mkdir();
    FileUtils.write(new File(confPath, "data-config.xml"), data_config_xml);
    FileUtils.write(new File(confPath, "schema.xml"), schema_xml);
    FileUtils.write(new File(confPath, "solrconfig.xml"), solrconfig_xml);
  }

  void startSolr() {
    System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", configPath.getAbsolutePath());
    CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
    CoreContainer coreContainer = initializer.initialize();
    server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "collection1");
  }

  @Before
  public void setup() throws IOException {
    populateDb(getDataSource());
    writeSolrConfig();
    startSolr();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    server.shutdown();
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(configPath);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSplitBy() throws Exception {
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.set("qt", "/dataimport");
    query.setParam("command", "full-import");
    QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
    Thread.sleep(500);

    response = server.query(new SolrQuery("*:*"));
    for (SolrDocument doc: response.getResults()) {
      assertNotNull(doc.getFieldValues("type"));
      assertEquals(3, doc.getFieldValues("type").size());
    }
  }
}
```

And the POM for the test case:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Solr Sanity</name>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-dataimporthandler</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.9</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any insight on how to get those types to split correctly into multiple values?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971476/splitting-multivalued-field-while-importing-data-into-solr

Comment: Yeah - I already examined that one (and every other duplicate answer SO suggested). Seems like the only difference in the solution to that one was to add the `sourceColName` attribute to the field in question (which I already tried). Just seems like there's something obvious that I'm missing. Is there a working example of the `splitBy` functionality somewhere?

Comment: What columm do you have in database? type or **types**? According to your definition it is types. Is that matching to what you actually have?

Comment: The DB column is `types`. I also tried naming it `type` as well (changing the definition accordingly). I thought maybe the `sourceColName` had to be different from `column`. Still had the same result...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there were a couple of issues with this unit test:

1. HSQL's column names are case sensitive (and default to upper case).
2. If the Solr field name and the db column name are identical an extra token with the entire db value is also added.
3. The field definition should look like:

```xml
<field column="solrField" splitBy="," sourceColName="TYPE" />
```

And in general - when using the `RegexTransformer` to mix single valued fields from a DB with multivalued fields:

- If using `splitBy` then the `column` attribute is the name of the Solr field. The `sourceColName` is the database column
- If *not* using `splitBy` then the `column` attribute is the database column name and the `name` attribute is the Solr field.